What causes the four proton signals closest to the carbonyl in tetraphenylcyclopentadienone to appear more upfield than the other 16 aromatic protons?
What causes the four proton signals closest to the carbonyl in tetraphenylcyclopentadienone to appear more upfield than the other 16 aromatic protons? It's my current understanding that the carbonyl would deshield the protons closest to it, causing them to appear more downfield, not upfield.
[Here is the NMR spectrum for tetraphenylcyclopentadienone from SDBS] (https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/direct_frame_disp.cgi?sdbsno=13741&spectrum_type=HNMR&fname=HSP48866)
